# Django infinite loop to access models

Tags: python, django, infinite-loop

I am a beginner in django and was doing a test here to access to a model in infinite loop. But while running the following code I found the memory is filled up quickly and end up with a memory leaking error.

Could anybody tell me what is the safe/simple way to access to model in a infinite loop? Should I use threading in this kind of program?

```
from patient_post.models import Patient
def messageScheduler():
    while 1:
    patients = Patient.objects.all()
    del patients
```

Comment: why would you want to do such a thing ? I dont see a practical usecase of accessing a queryset infinitely.

Comment: I wanted to access the queryset and do some operation each iteration. There could be sleep() statement inside but it didn't make any change.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of operation do you need to do on every iteration?

Comment: Like save some other objects to the database every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a job scheduler for such thing, you have multiple options with different features and complexity and your choice will depend on your requirements. Here is some examples:

[django-chronograph](https://bitbucket.org/wnielson/django-chronograph)

[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)

[django-rq](https://github.com/ui/django-rq)

Another option is to create management task and run it using a cron job.